# Multiple Optional Different Parameters in mod_rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm stuck in a pretty complex rule I'm trying to get done.
I have 4 different optional parameters which are displayed in different forms.

I've been using a really long set of rules but it came to the point of I can't make it work with more than one parameter.

My code so far is like this.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^library/from/([0-9]+)$ library.php?year=$1
RewriteRule ^library/upto/([0-9]+)$ library.php?year2=$1
RewriteRule ^library/([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)$ library.php?year=$1&year2=$2
RewriteRule ^library/query=(.*)$ library.php?query=$1
RewriteRule ^library/([a-z-]+)$ library.php?category=$1
RewriteRule ^library/([a-z-]+)?/([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)?/query=(.*)?$ library.php?category=$1&year=$2&year2=$3&query=$4
```

The year part has 3 different sets. Its 2 variables and 3 outputs, based on which one of them is missing.
Is there a way to fix it or clean it up and use a smarter way?
EDIT. It is working with all 4 parameters.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which URL is in't rewriting for you and what it should rewrite to?

Comment: I want several different URL's, but one example is http://localhost/fluid/library/accessibility-of-health-services/1986-2014/query=example to become http://localhost/fluid/library.php?category=accessibility-of-health-services&year1=1986&year2=2014&query=example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^library/from/([0-9]+)/?$ library.php?year=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^library/upto/([0-9]+)/?$ library.php?year2=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^library/([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)/?$ library.php?year=$1&year2=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^library/query=(.+)$ library.php?query=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^library/([a-z-]+)/?$ library.php?category=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^library/([a-z-]+)/([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)?/query=(.+)$ library.php?category=$1&year=$2&year2=$3&query=$4 [L,QSA]
```